# find center point of a polygon in js

Tags: javascript, prototype, canvas

I have found a nice [example](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/polyarea/) how to find the center point of a polygon ([and here in JS](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/polyarea/javascript.txt)):

-> See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxzJ5/1/) example

So, with this polygon

```
var polygon = [
     {'x':770, 'y':400},
     {'x':529, 'y':643},
     {'x':320, 'y':494},
     {'x':424, 'y':381},
     {'x':459, 'y':369}
];
```

I should find the center point like so:

```
var con = new Contour();
    con.pts = polygon;
    document.write(con.centroid)
```

But `con.centroid` is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the `Contour` constructor way before the `Contour` prototype has been defined.  In the said jsfiddle, move your `document.write` to the end, and all will go... better.

Also, you need to actually call the `centroid` function you defined:

```
var c = con.centroid();
document.write( c.x );
document.write( c.y );
```

Comment: errm.. yes.. I really need to do more of this prototype stuff. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here's fixed version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxzJ5/2/)

You've made few mistakes 
- first of all you've declared Contour and Point after calling them - thus you weren't able to use it.
- you called centroid as if it was property and it was a function thus you were missing brackets () after centroid
- in return value of centroid function you passed x and y as an Object where function point takes x and y as separate values

Answer (score 3):

first of all you should define everything before creating your "new Contour". Moreover, centroid is a function, so you should invoke it using `con.centroid()` . Apparently you want that function to return a "point" but I do not think that is the correct way do to that. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/SsCux/3/

PS: I think there is something wrong in the calculation of the area